# How to assign a value to certain indices of a Numpy array when the indices are given in another numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python and even more so to NumPy and I couldnt find a solution for this for now.
I have a Numpy array `a = [1 4 6]` and another `b` that consists of 3 rows and 3 cols full of zeros

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

How can I assign a certain value `v` to exactly the 3 indexes of a of b
My idea would be something like this

```
for x in range(a):
        b[x] = v
```

which doesn't work. I also tried it with converting `a` to a `list()` beforehand

Comment: Please provide an explicit/complete (no `...`) and reproducible (keep the commas) example.

Comment: @mozway Ok, I have edited it to break it down to a very simple scheme. What do you mean by commas? In the output of my console there are no commas with these numpy arrays.

Comment: `a = np.array([1, 4, 6])` is reproducible, `a = [1 4 6]` is not If you don't use `print`, the python interpreter should output the array with commas. Can you also provide the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to assign a value `v=1` in the nth indices of the flatten array `b`, you could use:

```
a = np.array([1, 4, 6])
b = np.zeros((3, 3))

b.flat[a] = 1
```

Or use [`numpy.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
b[np.unravel_index(a, b.shape)] = 1
```

Output:

```
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: the unravel index did exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot